# Flat spin connections in pseudo-Riemann spacetimes of dimension 4.

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

I want to understand flat spin connections in a pseudo Riemann spacetime of dimension 4 (over Lorentz manifolds). They appear in the context of the frame formalism of metric gravity theories. I believe that they form a subspace, homologous to the algebra of the Lorentz group, within the affine space of spin connections. The dimension of the subspace would be then 6. However, I cannot prove this idea myself. Does anybody can help (or correct) me with this?

Comment: Flat connections do not form a linear subspace. Also, the dimension (even after you mod out by the gauge group) need not be 6, as far as I can tell, it could be pretty much any number, depending on the manifold. You should also specify how your spin connections relate to the Lorentzian metric on the manifold.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. First notice the mistake in the title. It reads now "Flat spin connections in pseudo-Riemann spacetimes of dimension 4". Let me give some more details. In a 4 dimensional pseudo-Riemann spacetime with signature (1,3) the algebra of the Lorentz group has dimension 6. The spin (Lorentz) connections form an affine space (dimension 24). My question is whether the flat spin connections form a subspace in this space. I want to (dis)prove that it is "homologous" to the Lorentz group, in the sense that flat connections can be written using the Lorentz group.